# Error while installing megasync desktop client on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 64

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I downloaded the .deb file from `https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_22.04/amd64/megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb`

```shell
wget https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_22.04/amd64/megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb && sudo apt install "$PWD/megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb"
```

but I get the following error:

```shell
$ sudo apt install ./megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'megasync' instead of './megasync-xUbuntu_22.04_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 megasync : Depends: libmediainfo0v5 (>= 0.7.56) but it is not installable
            Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.1) but it is not installable
            Depends: libqt5dbus5 (>= 5.14.1) but it is not installable
            Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.14.1) but it is not installable or
                     libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.14.1) but it is not installable
            Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.14.1) but it is not installable
            Depends: libqt5svg5 (>= 5.6.0~beta) but it is not installable
            Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.11.0~rc1) but it is not installable
            Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libzen0v5 (>= 0.4.31-2~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any idea about how to solve this issue?

--- alternatively I tried to add megasync repository following this guide

https://help.mega.io/installs-apps/desktop-syncing/linux

```
For Ubuntu 21.04 that would be:

1. Configure MEGA’s public signing key:

curl -fsSL https://mega.nz/keys/MEGA_signing.key | sudo apt-key add -

2. Add MEGA to your repositories

https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_21.04/

3. Then you can use your system tool for installing our packages.

sudo apt update && sudo apt install megasync
```

How can I add the repository for `https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_22.04`

I tried adding `deb https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_22.04 jammy main` but it didn't work:

```shell
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                      
Get:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease [3.569 B]                                
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                         
Get:6 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main armhf Packages [21,4 kB]                      
Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease                 
Get:8 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main amd64 Packages [21,3 kB]                     
Get:9 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main arm64 Packages [21,3 kB]                      
Ign:10 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_22.04 jammy InRelease                                          
Hit:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu jammy InRelease   
Err:12 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_22.04 jammy Release 
  404  Not Found [IP: 31.216.144.5 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_22.04 jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 0):

my bad, sorry, I just had to enable the `universe` repository